# How to set tab space keybinding in UTOP

Tags: terminal, ocaml, utop

I'm thinking I have to somehow edit my ~/.lambda-term-inputrc file but I'm lost as to what actually to write in it.

Comment: What do you mean by the "tab space keybinding"?

Comment: I mean I want to be able to tab space for indentation instead of regular space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by similar steps to what ivg suggested by instead changing C-i with tab 
"tab: insert( ), insert( ), insert( ), insert( )"

Answer (score 0):

While I'm totally not sure that it is a good idea to bind `<tab>` to spaces in the interactive shell where `<tab>` is used for completion, you can achieve this using the following `~/.lambda-term-inputrc`,

```
[read-line]
[edit]
C-i: insert( ), insert( ), insert( ), insert( )
```

Explanation, here `C-i` is the Emacs way of saying `<tab>`, and a series of `insert( )` will insert four spaces, instead of a tabulation.

P.S. This might not work, however, since lambda-term may treat  specially.

Comment: Yeh, i put this in my ~/.lambda-term-inputrc file but it didn't work. Also, what do you mean by "lamda-term may treat specially"?

Comment: I meant that tab is a special case for utop and lambda-term so that they will intercept it before the inputrc translation.